# Entity Framework Server Side Computed Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm consuming an api that has the following class for time.

```
public class CRTime
{
    public DateTime? datetime { get; set; }
    public string timezone { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to translate that into a single DateTime field.

Here is an example of the full object that is returned to me and how I am trying to calculate the DateTime field that will then be stored in the database.

```
public class ReturnObject
{
    [NotMapped]
    // This comes from the api, but is not synced to database
    public CRTime CRCreated { get; set; }

    // this is stored in our db, should be calculated from CRCreated
    public DateTime? CreatedDB { get
        {
            var val = (CRCreated != null) ? CRCreated.datetime : null;
            return val;
        }
        private set { }
    }
    // other fields go here
}
```

This works perfect on record create, but when I try and update the record using the Entity.Migration framework and AddOrUpdate, the update overwrites the value and always sets it to NULL.

What is the best solution for creating a server side computed column that then gets synced to the database.

Side Note: I am using NewtonSoft Json to deserialize the object into my entity framework object, then passing that to Entity Framework AddOrUpdate.

Comment: thinking through things, maybe there is an issue since the CRCreated property is not stored in the database, so on update, entity framework has trouble doing the comparison and running the compute on it since it's getting it's value from the db where it is null instead of from the object from coming from the api?

Comment: I also tried using [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] attribute, but this is meant for doing calculation on the db side, which doesn't have info into CRCreated object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a rather confusing quirk of `AddOrUpdate`.

`AddOrUpdate` determines if an entity is new or existing, obviously. It does that by querying the database for the entity by its primary key, or some key you can specify. Now two things can happen:

- It doesn't find the entity in the database; your entity object is marked as `Added`.
- It does find an entity, but contrary to what you'd expect your entity object is still `Detached`! The found entity *remains hidden* and this is the object EF updates in the end. It copies the values from your own entity to it, which may mark the hidden entity as `Modified`.

Obviously, by this empty setter, `CreatedDB` will always be `null` when it's fetched from the database. For EF, `CRCreated` doesn't exist. It probably reads a `CreatedDB` value from your object, but again the empty setter prevents it from being copied to the hidden object and it gets updated as `null`.

You have to decide how to fix this. Probably the best way is to make the setter actually modify (or create) the `CRCreated` instance.

Alternatively, you can do away with `AddOrUpdate` and try to find the existing object yourself. If you find it, it's not hidden anymore, so you can do with it whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect it to be NULL after you read it from the Db. The `private set;` is of course weird and blocks the proper working of EF.

You could do your self a great favour when you are able to use DateTimeOffset but in the current situation:

Your property might be logically 'calculated' but towards the database it should be treated and implemented as a normal read/write property.